# How to group by on a reference type property in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class like this:

```
public class Order
{
  public int Id;
  public Person SalesPerson;
  ...
}
public class Person
{
  public int Id;
  public string Name;
  ...
}
```

I writed a query in LINQ like this:

```
Order[] orders = GetAllOrders();
var myResult = select o from orders
               group o by o.SalesPerson.Id into oGroup
               select new {SalesPersonId = oGroup.Key, Order = oGroup}
```

It work correctly. But I will group on SalesPerson object not on SalesPersonId. When I group by SalesPerson its not group correctly even I impelement `IEquatable<Person>` interface but it doesn't work still. what should I do?

tanx for your help.

Comment: What's your .Equals() and .GetHashCode() implementation on Person? You should always override both if they mean anything to you. Also - accepting questions helps motivating people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

oh yes,  Benjamin Podszun is right. I should override `GetHashCode()` method too.
so my class is like this:

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{ 
  public int Id; 
  public string Name; 
  ... 

  public bool Equals(Person other)
  {
    return other == null ? false : this.Id == other.Id;
  }
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return this.Id.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

thank you